# php include from higher directory

Tags: php

I have a directory structure like so:

```
/
 index.php
 global.php
 classes/
   class1.php
   class2.php
 management/
   manage.php
```

In index.php, I `require_once "global.php"`.

In global.php, I do `foreach(glob("classes/*") as $filename) { require_once $filename }` to require all of my classes. Later on in global.php, I need to instantiate one of these classes.

Now, I am working on the management portion of my site, so in `management/manage.php` I need access to all of my classes. If i do `require_once "../global.php"`, that file is included fine, but later in global.php when I need to instantiate one of the classes, I get an error saying that class cannot be found.

When I am working with the files in the top level directory, I can use all of my classes within global.php with no trouble. It is only when I include global.php from management/manage.php that this error pops up, saying that the class cannot be found. The source of the error is reported as a line in global.php.

How can I correctly include all of the necessary files? I would prefer to keep all of my classes included once from global.php.

Comment: What you *really* need is an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). I 'm not posting an answer because you asked for something quite different, but that's what you should do. See https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Comment: use absolute path in global.php

Comment: use `glob(dirname(__FILE__) ."/classes/*")`.  This constructs an absolute path based on the location of global.php

Comment: Autoloading would be a much better idea if the class files are *just* defining classes (which they really should be anyway).  If other stuff is being defined in there, like helper functions, they will magically appear when certain classes are referred to by running code.  Which makes things a bit wacky.  So if you do decide to autoload, make sure the non-class stuff is defined in some file(s) you always include.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess it's time to rewrite with autoloaders

Comment: @parker.sikand once you have achieved your goal, please answer you own question and accept your one answer, for the benefit of future users.